# Not able to reconnect to a docker container with /dev folder mounted

Tags: linux, docker, serial-port

I'm trying to use a docker container to run a [`micro_ros_agent`](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_linux/) on a Raspberry Pi 4. As the Micro Ros tutorial suggests, I started the whole thing using this command:
`docker run -it --net=host -v /dev:/dev --privileged ros:foxy`
Everything worked fine yesterday, but after rebooting the Pi and trying to connect to the container doesn't work anymore. Running `docker ps -a` shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
abb35dfade78   b22ec88562e6   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   41 hours ago    Created                               magical_colden
7a61e34f62bd   b22ec88562e6   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   41 hours ago    Exited (0) 41 hours ago               heuristic_galileo
615f951f2c8a   b22ec88562e6   "/ros_entrypoint.sh …"   41 hours ago    Exited (0) 41 hours ago               charming_wozniak
```

When I run `docker start -ai abb35dfade78` I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: open /dev/console: permission denied: unknown
```

So I thought when permission was denied I'll need sudo, so I ran `sudo !!` and now it reports:

```
Error: No such container: magical_colden
```

which seems very odd to me, as the container definitely exists.
After some digging I found out, that the issue is probably related to the fact, that the device folder or some files in the device folder don't exist anymore and therefor the mounting fails. However, I couldn't find out how to fix this issue or how to do the whole thing entirely different so that the issue doesn't appear in the first place. I want to use the Micro ROS agent for a serial connection, so I definitely need the `/dev` folder in my docker container. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I've never found a need for `docker start`.  Does deleting and recreating the container work?  (A container is a wrapper around a single process, and all of your other processes got lost on reboot.)  If you have a privileged container with access to all host devices, does it need to be in a container at all, or will a host process be easier to manage?

Comment: @DavidMaze I would prefer not using a container, but this is the recommended setup for using ROS2 and/or Micro ROS on Raspberry Pi. Raspberry PI OS does only receive Tier 3 support and it seems very complicated to setup ROS2 on it. What exactly do you mean by deleting and recreating the container?

Comment: `docker rm magical_colden`, and then repeat the initial `docker run` command you used to start the container the first time.